# Unable to resolve module `./Linking/Linking` from `node_modules/expo/build/ExpoLazy.js`

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Has anyone experience this error with expo, when running `react-native run-android`?

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./Linking/Linking` from `node_modules/expo/build/ExpoLazy.js`: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/expo/build/Linking/Linking(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * node_modules/expo/build/Linking/Linking/index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
```

"expo": "^37.0.9",

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just ran into this issue, downgrade to 37.0.8 (no caret) and do an `npm i`.  Looks like they released 37.0.9 yesterday and it has an issue.

Comment: thank you very much, i just solve it downgrading to ~37.0.3 :)

Comment: Sorry, how can I downgrade the sdk? I cannot find anything on google

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me:

1) In package.json change to `"expo": "37.0.8"`
2) Delete your node_modules 
3) installl packages `npm i`
4) clean cache in expo `expo r -c`

Now it started to work again. Couldn't find the last step in previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Internal bug of react-native. You don't have much of a choice, as user3916570 consider downgrading.

Answer (score 0):

For now, downgrading Expo to 37.0.8 fixed this. To downgrade, in your package.json, change your Expo dependency to:

```
"expo": "37.0.8",
```

Then remove your node_modules and reinstall everything:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an expo version problem only, you should also check the global expo-cli version and probably node as well.
Run:

```sh
$ npm install -g expo-cli --force 
$ rm -rf node_modules/ 
$ rm -rf package-lock.json 
# (in my case mac '$ brew upgrade node && npm install -g npm') 
$ npm install 
$ npm run
```